# How to center a form inside a Bootstrap 4 jumbotron

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

```html
<div class="jumbotron text-center" id="jumbotron">
  <h1 class="display-3">Lorem Ipsum</h1>
  <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum</p>
  <hr class="my-y-2">
  <p>################</p>
  <form class="form-inline">

    <label class="sr-only" for="email">Email</label>
    <div class="input-group mb-2 mr-sm-2">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <div class="input-group-text">@</div>

        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email">
      </div>

    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Sign Up</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

I'm trying to have this form inside a jumbotron and be at the center of it but I can't seem to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **Bootstrap 4** class you need in this case is `justify-content-center`.

Here's the working code:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="jumbotron text-center" id="jumbotron">
    <h1 class="display-3">Lorem Ipsum</h1>
    <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum</p>
    <hr class="my-y-2">
    <p>################</p>
    <form class="form-inline justify-content-center">

        <label class="sr-only" for="email">Email</label>
        <div class="input-group mb-2 mr-sm-2">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <div class="input-group-text">@</div>

                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email">
            </div>

        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Sign Up</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't posted any CSS so it's hard to understand where you are going wrong. But centering your form could be achieved wrapping your form in a

Example: [JSFiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/dm6w8gk1/1/)

```
#form-align
  {
   display: block;
   text-align: center;
 }
form
  {
   display: inline-block;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: Im sorry i wasnt very specific.I want to know if there is a bootstrap class that can center the form.Thanks for your answer though!